# Unable to access the Azure Web App after deployment from Azure AI Studio with gpt3.5 Turbo model

Tags: authentication, azure-appservice, azure-openai

Team,

Need some help here.

I created gpt3.5 model deployment in Azure AI Studio and used "Add your Data" feature.

Added a pdf file to Azure AI search and fed to my model which is working absolutely fine in Chat Playground.

Deployed to Web App using the top right window option "Deploy to a new web app " in AI Studio. Post Deployment unable to access the web app.

Point 1 : Its asking to set up Authentication. Not allowing me to access by default

Point 2 : Added an Identity using Microsoft Service Principal. Now when attempted to access the web app its asking for Azure AD credentials(ID / Pwd)  which a service principal doesnt have.

Can anyone help here!

Comment: Before deployment the window gives you below  comment
`Your web app will be configured with Azure Active Directory authentication enabled. It may take a few minutes to apply after deployment completes, during which time you will not be able to chat in the app. Please wait 10 minutes, then reload the app and log in to begin chatting.`

Answer (score 0):

The sample deployed using the button in Azure OpenAI Studio is open-sourced [here](https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT).

Regarding point 1 - asking for authentication setup, if you really want it, you can remove it by following the process detailed in this section: https://github.com/microsoft/sample-app-aoai-chatGPT?tab=readme-ov-file#add-an-identity-provider

```
To remove this restriction, you can add AUTH_ENABLED=False to the environment variables. This will disable authentication and allow anyone to access the chat functionality of your app. This is not recommended for production apps.
```

Regarding point 2, you need to understand how authentication works with App Services and Entra ID:

- you define a new Application / Service principal in Entra ID
- you set Authentication on your web app, using "Microsoft" provider, and use this App (its client ID) and also set its secret as a configuration variable
- then you can call your webapp, using the credentials of someone in listed as a user in the same Entra ID tenant (and you can apply restrictions if needed), so you should here use simply user credentials